# When I use onkeyup in HTML for a JS function why does console say my function is not defined?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a registration form which has a textbox for confirming your password.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    label {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 100px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    
    body {
      font-family: sans-serif;
    }
  </style>

  <title>Register</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h2>Register</h2>
  <form method="post" action="">
    Username:<br>
    <input type="text" name="username"><br><br> Email Addres: <br>
    <input type="text" name="email"><br><br> Password:
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="password"><br><br> Confirm Password:<br>
    <input type="text" name="passwordconf" onkeyup="passVal()"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
<script>
  var pass = document.getElementsByName("password");
  var confPass = document.getElementsByName("passwordconf");

  function passVal() {
    if (pass.value != confPass.value) {
      confPass.setCustomValidity("Passwords don't match");
    } else {
      confPass.setCustomValidity("");
    }
  }
</script>
```

The intent is that whenever a key is released (onkeyup), a function runs which checks to see if the contents of the textboxes are equal (passVal). When I run it add text to both of the password boxes, errors show up in the console saying that passVal is not defined.

I tried making passval equal to a variable

```
var variableExample = passVal;
```

and using onkeyup to call the variable, but this made no difference. Except, that now the console said variableExample was not defined instead of passVal. I have no clue why this is not working. Anyone know how I might fix this?

Comment: Well that function should be called, but I do see an issue where you have `document.getElementsByName` and treat what is in pass and confPass as a element and not an HTML collection.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a tour at https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Please post your error. Does it say `setCustomValidity` is undefined? Or passVal is undefined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    label {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 100px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    
    body {
      font-family: sans-serif;
    }
  </style>

  <title>Register</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h2>Register</h2>
  <form method="post" action="">
    Username:<br>
    <input type="text" name="username"><br><br> Email Addres: <br>
    <input type="text" name="email"><br><br> Password:
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="password"><br><br> Confirm Password:<br>
    <input type="text" name="passwordconf" onkeyup="passVal()"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
<script>
  var pass = document.getElementsByName("password")[0];
  var confPass = document.getElementsByName("passwordconf")[0];

  function passVal() {
    if (pass.value != confPass.value) {
      console.log('Not equal');
    } else {
      console.log('Equal');
    }
  }
</script>
```

If you query by [`.getElementsByName()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbyname.asp), you'll get an array of elements, as does [`.getElementsByTagName()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbytagname.asp). Notice that "Element" is plural.

If you only want one element, just use [`.getElementsById()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried making the changes you selected including switching to ID, but I got the same error message in console.

Comment: This morning I tried putting the new code with the changes in a different emulator and it worked. Thanks again. It must have been a problem with repl.it.

Answer (score 0):

*getElementsByName* return an array of elements,
You should use *id* instead or get the fist element of array (*pass[0]*)

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I tried changing getElementsByName to getElementById for both of my variables and added IDs to the variables. However, the same error still showed up in console.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to fix here is how you are getting the element value which is by using

```
var pass = document.getElementsByName("passwordconf")
```

which returns an array of all the elements with the name `passwordconf`.

Adding `.value` to variable `pass` will then return undefined because you did not define which element in the array are you trying to get. You can add `[0]` to get the first element in the array (array indexing always starts count with `0`) like this:

```
pass[0].value;
```

Note that by doing this, you will not get the `passVal is not defined` error.